# Infinite loop caused by require(gWidgetstcltk)

Tags: r, gwidgets

When I `require(gWidgetstcktk)`, I get an infinite loop, with a seemingly endless number of error messages that look like this:

```
error reading package index file /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library/tcltk2/tklibs/ttktheme_clearlooks/pkgIndex.tcl: can't find package tile
error reading package index file /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library/tcltk2/tklibs/ttktheme_clearlooks/pkgIndex.tcl: too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)
```

(On each iteration the path is different. The end of these messages seem to be the important parts: `can't find package tile` and `too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)`

I installed the packages as usual using `install.package()` and the files referred to seem to be present. `gWidgets` seems to load just fine. I'm running R 2.14.1  via RStudio 0.96.231 on OSX 10.7.4. What is going wrong here?

---

Update: I now see that the problem is coming from the `tcltk2` package.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen.  First off, I'd say try uninstalling the package and then re-installing it.  There might have been an error during the process.  Another thing you should do is select "Install All Dependencies" when you do this (or `install.packages(______, dependencies = TRUE)`).  Have you installed all of the package's relevant dependencies?  Perhaps this library requires a different library which you don't have.

Comment: Ahh - I thought that dependencies defaulted to TRUE, but now I see that it doesn't. I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Sadly, no. I've uninstalled it and reinstalled it, and there's no change. I've also confirmed that this only happens with gWidgetstcltk   - other packages install just fine.

Comment: I don't see the issue with the checks on CRAN. My guess is your issue sits with the `tcltk2` package. I removed that dependency recently, but notice that CRAN keeps two versions 0.0-52 and 0.0-49 (which has the `tcltk2` dependency). Not sure what you are picking up. Can you try loading the `tcltk2` package directly and see if the problem rests there?

Comment: Yep, `require(tcltk2)` causes the same problem. How do I deal with this? I tried removing `tcltk2` followed by `require(gWidgetstcltk)`, which fail with the error `‘package ‘tcltk2’ could not be loaded’`